# Can LoRa end points communicate directly?

Tags: lora

Can LoRa end points communicate directly?

Or is a gateway/network server always required?

Comment: I think the distinction you are looking for is LoRa vs LoRaWAN

Comment: Care to post an answer, with explanation? Or even just a URL to the explanation? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I think that you are saying that LoRaWAN can communicate directly, but plain LoRa needs the gateway, etc. Would that be correct?

Comment: No, wrong way round

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, LoRa can do point to point communication. There are many examples of people using LoRa between 2 devices for low power, low bandwidth notifications between devices e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV_VumvI-0A

The hub/spoke topology is normally associated with the LoRaWAN implementations (e.g. [The Things Network](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/)) used for building wide area support for devices to communicate with a cloud backend.